# Python: How many times does the least common string appear?

Tags: python, function, csv

This is a example of a csv file it is linked to the code

[image: csv image]

I want to know how to find How many times does the least common string appear in the field [gas]

```
def least_string(gas):
    if  gas in gasdic:
        gasdic[gas] += 1
    else:
        gasdic[gas] = 1
```

I change the first half in to function

```
if  gas in gasCount:
     gasCount[gas] += 1
else:
    gasCount[gas] = 1
```

It printed out

```
{'Nitrogen': 3, 'Methane': 3, 'Helium': 2, 'CarbonDioxide': 1, ' Chlorine': 3, 'Oxygen': 3, 'Xenon': 1, 'Hydrogen': 2, 'Argon': 1}
```

I need to change this in to function

```
smallest = 100000
for key in gasCount:
    if gasCount[key] < smallest:
        smallest = gasCount[key]

answers = []
for key in gasCount:
    if gasCount[key] == smallest:
        answers.append(key)
```

so it would print out

```
The least common string appear in the field [gas]: ['CarbonDioxide', 'Xenon', 'Argon']
```

This is the full code

```
import string

def getFile():
    filename = input('Filename: ') #the file name should be .csv
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    firstline = True

    Line = file.readline()
    if Line == None or Line == '':
        return None

    if firstline: # I do not want to read the field names
        Line = file.readline() # there is more to read
        firstline = False # so I skip them. the code assuems 

    return file

#Count the number of (T's) in the field [correct]
def calcT(correct):
    global tCount
    found = False
    for ch in correct:#look at each character in turn
        if ch in 'tT':
            found = True

    if found:
        tCount +=1
#How many times does the least common string appear in the field [gas]
def least_string(gas):
    if  gas in gasdic:
        gasdic[gas] += 1
    else:
        gasdic[gas] = 1


#Find the sum of the values in the field [quant] less than (408)
def sum_quant(quant):
    global qsum
    if quant < 408:
        qsum += quant

#How many values in the 'code' field do not match the format 9999(x9+)9?
def checkString(astring):
    if len(astring)  != 10:
        return False
    if not astring[0] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[1] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[2] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[3] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[4]=='(':
        return False
    if not astring[5] in string.ascii_lowercase:
        return False
    if not astring[6] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[7]=='+':
        return False
    if not astring[8]==')':
        return False
    if not astring[9] in string.digits:
        return False
    return True



#What is the average value of the numbers in the field [age] in the range (30) and (107) inclusive 
def average_age(age):
    global tAge, ageCount
    if age >= 30 and age <=107:
        tAge += age
    ageCount += 1

#Find the sum of the numbers in field [length] between (2.482) and (6.428) inclusive 
def sum_Length(leng):
    global lensum
    if leng >= 2.482 and leng <= 6.428:
        lensum += leng

#count the lines where gas's have the value (Nitrogen) *or* quant is less than 318
def calcGas(gas, quant):
    global clines
    if gas == 'Nitrogen' or quant < 318:
        clines += 1

def processLine(Line):
    Line = Line.strip()
    fields = Line.split(',')

    correct = fields[0]
    gas = fields[1]
    quant = int(fields[2])
    code = fields[3]
    if checkString(code):
        global cCount
        cCount += 1
    age = int(fields[4])
    leng = float(fields[5])
    calcT(correct)
    sum_Length(leng)
    calcGas(gas, quant)
    average_age(age)
    sum_quant(quant)
    least_string(gas)


def processFile(data):

    for line in data:
        processLine(line)

    data.close()

def displayResults():
    #Count the number of (T's) in the field [correct]
    print('The number of (T) in the field [correct]: %d'%(tCount))
    print('-' *10)
    print(gasdic)
    print('The least common string appear in the field [gas]:%s'%(answers))
    print('-' *10)
    #Find the sum of the values in the field [quant] less than (408)
    print('The sum of the values in the field [quant] less than (408): %d'%(qsum))
    print('-' *10)
    #How many values in the 'code' field do not match the format 9999(x9+)9?
    print('The values in the code field do not match the format 9999(x9+)9: %d'%(cCount))
    print('-' *10)
    #What is the average value of the numbers in the field [age] in the range (30) and (107) inclusive
    print('The average value of numbers in the field[age] in range(30)and(107):%0.2f'%((tAge/ageCount)))
    print('-' *10)
    #Find the sum of the numbers in field [length] between (2.482) and (6.428) inclusive 
    print('The sum of the numbers in field [length] between (2.482) and (6.428): %6.3f'%(lensum))
    print('-' *10)
    #count the lines where gas's have the value (Nitrogen) *or* quant is less than 318
    print('The lines where gas have the value (Nitrogen) *or* quant is less than 318: %d' %(clines))


tCount = 0
qsum = 0
gasdic = {}
answers =[]
cCount = 0
ageCount = 0
tAge = 0
lensum = 0
clines = 0
myfile = getFile()
processFile(myfile)
displayResults()
```

Comment: Looks like we are helping with homework

Comment: @yderazer1992: if the questions are not duplicates, then please edit your question to show how they are different or why the answer to the other post did not solve your specific issues.

Comment: I'm not following you there, sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am doing an assignment and I have wriiten a code to answer my question  which is a csv file I have to change most of the code into function and then i have to change function ton class and then GUI but there is one question i am stuck on which is to find the least common string i need to change that to make it work

Comment: Right, and the other question covers how to find the least common string; you use a counter object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i think i use a counter object

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have added an image of what the csv file contain

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import Counter

def least_common(ls):
    c = Counter(ls)
    m = min(c.values())
    return [k for k, v in c.items() if v == m]

least_common('Foo Bar FooBar Bar'.split()) # ['FooBar', 'Foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def least_common(iterable):
    result = list()
    maximum = max([iterable.count(x) for x in set(iterable)])
    for length in range(maximum + 1):
        for word in set(iterable):
            if iterable.count(word) is length:
                result.append(word)
        if len(result):
            return result
```

Steps taken:

1. Get the maximum size so that we have a meaningful boundary.
2. Loop through an ascending range.
3. Loop through the iterable, in this case it might be gases.
4. If the result list has a non-zero length, we already have the least common; return!

Answer (score 1):

You could [sort](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-python-dictionaries-by-key-or-value/) the dictionary by value.

```
>>> a={'Nitrogen': 3, 'Methane': 3, 'Helium': 2, 'CarbonDioxide': 1, ' Chlorine': 3, 'Oxygen': 3, 'Xenon': 1, 'Hydrogen': 2, 'Argon': 1}
>>> sorted(a, key=a.__getitem__)
['Argon', 'CarbonDioxide', 'Xenon', 'Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Oxygen', 'Nitrogen', ' Chlorine', 'Methane']
```

Answer (score 0):

A [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be handy here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def least_string(gas_dict):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for gas in gas_dict:
        count[gas] += 1
    min_count = min(i[1] for i in count.items())
    return [k for k,v in count.items() if v == min_count]
```

Possible test case:

```
>>> word_list = "Foo Bar Foobar Bar".split()
>>> print(least_string(word_list))
['Foo', 'Foobar']
```

Comment: would this work if the it in the csv file